# Show clipped content in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

Is it possible to show content that falls outside of a nib's border, similar to how you can view clipped content when you debug the view hierarchy for a running application instance?

Comment: Pretty sure you have to use the debug view hierarchy features in order to view clipped content.